# How to create a struts 2 project using m2eclipse plugin using Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, struts2

I usually create my projects with maven 2 using the command line.  Im not quite sure how to do this using m2eclipse plugin in Eclipse Indigo with maven 3 on a Mac running OSX Lion. 
Im doing ok using this steps

1. File
2. New
3. Others
4. Maven
5. Maven Project

but cant find the struts 2 blank archetype from the Nexus Indexer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700817/help-for-use-maven-artifacts

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi it seems the only problem i have is an outdated artifact index.  how do i update my m2eclipse artifact index?

Comment: unfortunately i never used m2eclipse and i relied always on command line which give me more power and flexibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of choosing the Nexus Indexer, select `Configure...` and then `Add Remote Catalog...` and enter this URL:

http://struts.apache.org/archetype-catalog.xml

Then select that catalog instead of the Nexus Indexer and you should see all of the struts2 archetypes.

Comment: Exactly the solution I was looking for.  Thanks @rees!