# Problems creating a Struts 2 project in Eclipse

Tags: struts2

Im having some problems creating a Struts 2 project from Maven. I saw this post on tackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128626/how-to-create-a-struts-2-project-using-m2eclipse-plugin-using-eclipse-indigo) which talks about creating your own remote catalog, however Eclipse is telling me that the catalog is empty.

Also after following myKongs notes I get to the part of converting the generated Maven project into a Java Web Project by entering **mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0** However this seems to only create a normal Java project - it cannot be run on a server.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: above command is for making project settle in eclipse enviornment and if your project is web-app there shd not be a problem in running it? are u able to export your project as war from Eclipse?

Comment: I exported the project into an empty dynamic web application - what now?

Comment: just import it as a project no need for dynamic web-application, use eclipse import project option.